# Is this an example of reference reassignment? C++11

Tags: c++11, reference

As I understand it, one cannot change the reference variable once it has been initialized. See, for instance, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in). However, here is a minmal working example which sort of does reassign it. What am I misunderstanding? Why does the example print both 42 and 43?

```
#include <iostream>

class T {
    int x;
public:
    T(int xx) : x(xx) {}

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &dst, T &t) {
        dst << t.x;

        return dst;
    }
};

int main() {
    auto t = T(42);
    auto q = T(43);
    auto &ref = t;
    std::cerr << ref << std::endl;
    ref = q;
    std::cerr << ref << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should try printing all 3 values out each time to make it clear to yourself what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That does not perform a reference reassignment. Instead, it **copy assigns** the object in variable `q` into the object referenced by `ref` (which is `t` in your example).

This also justifies why you got 42 as output: the default copy assignment operator modified the first object.

Answer (score 4):

You're not changing the reference here.

You are replacing the object the reference is referring to.

In other words: after the assignment, your `t` is replaced by `q`.

`ref` is still a reference to `t`.